# Can I put a convection toaster oven over the range?

Tags: appliances, kitchens

My over-the-range microwave died and I want to replace it with a convection toaster oven.

I would love it to be put where the microwave was, over the stove. Can I do this? I have looked for over-the-range convection toaster ovens, and there seems to be no one selling them.  Do they exist? Is it safe to put one over the stove?

Answer (score 5):

Try searching for an [over the range convection microwave](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=above%20range%20convection%20microwave#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbm=shop&source=hp&q=over%20the%20range%20convection%20microwave&pbx=1&oq=over%20the%20range%20convection%20microwave&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=39075l39778l1l40420l8l5l1l0l0l1l138l488l3.2l5&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=3927a515d44d875c&biw=1348&bih=941) on Google Product search. This type of oven combines the quick heating ability of a microwave and the browning feature of a convection oven.

As for your question of safety: Yes it's safe, as long as the oven was designed to be installed over a range/stove. Since you'll be boiling water, cooking, etc. on the stove below it, the design should incorporate some sort of exhaust fan or other method to deal with the resulting steam. Otherwise accumulated moisture could damage the appliance or possibly create a safety hazard with the possibility of an electrical short.

Answer (score 1):

the only way it would be safe to put it over the stove is if you find one that is rated to be installed over a stove.

instead, you might want to try and find a microwave that has a browning element or an integrated toaster.